# Ruby convert string ($100.99) to float or BigDecimal

Tags: ruby, regex

I am capturing a page object “$100.99” as a string. Is there way to convert this to a float or BigDecimal as “100.99”?

I tried `xyz.scan(/\d+/).join().to_i` but that removes the decimal.

Comment: Why are you calling `to_i` if you want a float?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `to_f` method, after removing `$` from the string:

```
'$100.99'.delete('$').to_f
# => 100.99
```

Same for `BigDecimal`:

```
require 'bigdecimal'
BigDecimal.new('$100.99'.delete('$'))
# => 100.99
```

Comment: Thank you, when i use bigdecimal on "$24.15" i'm getting "0.2415E2". What am i doing wrong.

Comment: @gola077: Nothing, that's the default. If you want to convert a BigDecimal to a String like "24.15", send [#to_s](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-to_s) with `'F'` as argument: `BigDecimal.new('$24.15'.delete('$')).to_s('F') == '24.15'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string  using the `$` as the delimiter

```
s = "$100.99"
s.split('$')[1].to_f # 100.99
```

Answer (score 1):

more ways

#### do it with sub or gsub

```
2.1.3 :001 > s = "$100.99"
 => "$100.99"
2.1.3 :002 > s.sub('$','').to_f
 => 100.99
2.1.3 :003 > s.gsub('$','').to_f
 => 100.99
```

#### by slice

```
2.1.3 :001 > s = "$100.99"
 => "$100.99"
2.1.3 :002 > s.slice! '$'
 => "$"
2.1.3 :003 > p s
"100.99"
 => "100.99"
```

#### by tr

```
2.1.3 :011 > s = "$100.99"
 => "$100.99"
2.1.3 :012 > s.tr('$','')
 => "100.99"
```